# {Kafka V 0.10.1}Producing message takes approximately 1 minute if any error occurs at async producer Apache Kafka x

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Im using asynchronous producer to send messages to the broker. If there is no any error in my callback, i see it takes approximately 0.3 seconds to produce message. But when I get below error [1], I see it takes 60 seconds to produce message.
But I do not see any message loss . All messages are available in the broker.
What causes this error? I see this delay in every 50 message I produced.
How can I increase the performance of the producer when I get this error?

**Code;**

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, this), new ProducerCallback ());



  private class ProducerCallback implements Callback {

        @Override

        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception ex) {

            if (ex != null) {

              log.error("Error when publishing messages to the topic. Topic :"+ recordMetadata.topic(),ex);

            }

        }

    }
```

**Producer properties**

```
acks=1

linger.ms=10

batch.size=51200

bootstrap.servers=aukk1.xx.com\:9092,aukk2.xx.com\:9092,aukk3.xx.com\:9092

key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

value.serializer=com.xx.KafkaPayloadSerializer
```

[1]

```
04:51:20,025 ERROR [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-673) Error executing user-provided callback on message for topic-partition RAW_XML1harveyzhu-1:: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.lxx.kafkamodels.KafkaPayload$ProducerCallback.onCompletion(KafkaPayload.java:204)
       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch.done(RecordBatch.java:109)
       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch.maybeExpire(RecordBatch.java:155)
       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortExpiredBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:245)
       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:205)
       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:147)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ex is not null, the first parameter 'RecordMetadata' is null, so that's why you see NPE while invoking recordMetadata.topic()

Comment: SO, I receive an exception in my callback handler but metadata is null? Why It is null?

Comment: This is probably because some produce batch's metadata is not available and times out. You could print the exception to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to produce the record metadata:

```
if (ex == null) {  
            logger.info("Successfully received the details as: \n" +  
                    "Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +  
                    "Partition:" + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +  
                    "Offset" + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +  
                    "Timestamp" + recordMetadata.timestamp());  
                      }  
  
         else {  
            logger.error("Can't produce,getting error",e);
```